# fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++

I am just running the code `build.sh`. However, I got the error message:

> /mnt/storage/easybuild/software/GCCcore/5.4.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61:
>   fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated.

and also this error:

> /mnt/storage/software/libraries/nvidia/cuda-9.0/bin/..//include/crt/host_config.h:179:40:
>   fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated.

I have checked the path: `/mnt/storage/easybuild/software/GCCcore/5.4.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include-fixed/`, there is a file "limits.sh", but the error still occurs.

Comment: limits.sh sounds like a shell script, not a header file. It was looking for limits.h (but the way I read that error, it was in that limits.h when it saw #include limits.h so it looked for another limits.h and failed to find that)

Comment: You seem to be building something (what is it?) using easybuild. It is unlikely that you will be able to include enough details of the build logs and build environment in this question to get a useful answer. Easybuild appears to have a community with irc and slack that may be better equipped to help you. Maybe try there?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks for your help. I will check it again

Comment: @jakub_d Many thanks for your help. I will try it then.